# How long is a 'typical' transaction time, and what factors influence this?

Tags: transaction-data

I am wondering how long it takes on average for XMR to be sent from one address to another (in particular, because right now BTC takes ages).

Also, what factors influence the time? e.g. Mixin level, amount of XMR?